# WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow() in RavenDB 4

Tags: ravendb, ravendb4

I can't seem to find the equivalent of `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()` in RavenDB 4 .NET Client API.

In previous versions this was available through `IRavenQueryable.Customize()`, but now it contains only `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOf()` and `WaitForNonStaleResults()`. The `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOf()` accepts only an ETag and no DateTime.

Also, I tried looking for `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite()`, but couldn't find that either. And I couldn't replicate the behaviour myself by using `IDocumentStore.GetLastWrittenEtag()` since it is not present in 4.0.

Digging around a bit more I found that the last ETag would be available on the `Raven.Client.Documents.Operations.DatabaseStatistics`-object received as a response of the `Raven.Client.Documents.Commands.GetStatisticsCommand`... But I can't figure out how to issue this command in 4.0 either :(

Any help on achieving this in RavenDB 4 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v4.0 you should only use `WaitForNonStaleResults`. It will work exactly as the `WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow` was working. It is asking the server to wait on the query until the currently max etag of all the collections in the query.

> Cutoff etag is used to check if the index has already process a
>   document with the given etag. Unlike Cutoff, which uses dates and is
>   susceptible to clock synchronization issues between machines, cutoff
>   etag doesn't rely on both the server and client having a synchronized
>   clock and can work without it.

`WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOf` is going to be removed from the client:
http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-9678